# AWS CLI command for S3 Standard Infrequently Access files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm using `aws cli` to `cp` files from EC2 to Amazon S3.

I wanted to use `--storage-class STANDARD_IA` for Standard Infrequently Access storage class but it does not recognize it as a valid option. The command returns only `REDUCED_REDUNDANCY` or `STANDARD` as options.

[According to this documentations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html), STANDARD_IA is what I should use.

Is this an issue with the `cli` or the command is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upgrade your aws CLI version, its available at least from

```
fhenri@machine:~$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.9.1 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/14.5.0 botocore/1.3.1
```

specifically it was introduced in [version 1.8.6](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/CLI/7507092461233524)

Comment: I'm still running aws-cli/1.2.9. Thanks for the answer.